# Determine if the given sequence converges or diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence defined as $x_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{j+1}{j^2}$ . We want to know if $(x_n)$ converges. The trouble I am having here is that the sum depends on $n$. We know the sequence $\frac{1}{n} \to 0$ and the series $ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{j+1}{j^2}$ diverges. It is not obvious if $(x_n)$ is a increase or decreasing sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write
$$x_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{j}+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{j^2}
  =y_n+z_n\ .$$
Since $\sum(1/j^2)$ converges, $z_n\to0$ and we only need to think about $y_n$.  By drawing the graph of $1/t$ and comparing areas under the graph from $t=1$ to $t=n$ you can see that
$$\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{j}<1+\log n\ .$$
You should now be able to prove that $y_n$ converges and so $x_n$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

$$x_n=\dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{k+1}{k^2}=\dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\left(\dfrac{k}{k^2}+\dfrac{1}{k^2}\right)=\dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\left(\dfrac{1}{k}+\dfrac{1}{k^2}\right).$$

Hence,

$$x_n=\dfrac{1}{n}H_n+\dfrac{1}{n}S_n.$$

Where $H_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k}$ and $S_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k^2}$

Note that

- $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}S_n=\zeta(2)=\pi^2/6$. See [Zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function)
- $H_n \sim \log n$. See [Harmonic sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29)

Finally,

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{n}H_n+\dfrac{1}{n}\pi^2/6=0,$$

since $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\log n}{n}=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence converges. $x_n = y_n + z_n + r_n$ with:

$y_n = \dfrac{H_n - lnn}{n}$, $z_n = \dfrac{lnn}{n}$, and $r_n = \dfrac{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{n^2}}{n}$. For large $n$ the numerator of$y_n$ is bounded above by$\gamma + 2$. So $y_n$ can be seen to go to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. $z_n$ also goes to $0$ as $n \to \infty$, and finally $r_n < \dfrac{\pi^2}{6n}$. So $z_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. So we have the conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence $y_j =\frac{j+1}{j^2}$ converges to 0.

For $N$ large enough, $j\ge N \implies |y_j|<\epsilon$.

Cut the sum in two parts: when $j<N$ the sum goes to zero as $A/N$.

When $j\ge N$ the sum goes to zero because each terms is small (so is their average, thanks to the triangle inequality).

Hence $x_n\to 0$.

---

without words:

$$
\limsup |x_n| \le
\limsup \frac{\sum_{j=1}^N |y_j|}n +
\limsup \frac{\sum_{j=N+1}^n |y_j|}n
=0 + \limsup \frac{\sum_{j=N+1}^n |y_j|}n
\\
\le  \frac{\sum_{j=N+1}^n \epsilon}n \le \epsilon
$$

for all $\epsilon$. Hence
$$
\limsup |x_n| = 0
\\
\lim x_n=0
$$

Comment: If $y_j = 1/\ln(j+1)$, $y_j \to 0$ but $x_n \sim \ln n \to \infty$.

Comment: are you saying that Cesaro's theorem is false? I am sure you are kidding.

Comment: @martycohen: are you sure it isn't $x_n\sim1/\ln n$?